# access variable inside an array [Kotlin]

Tags: kotlin

It is a program using array to hold running paths. fun `printMaxMinPath()` is to print out the longest and shortest paths. My questions are:

1. how can i get access to the length of Runningpath and find the max and min? if i write the code as below, line 19, 20 won't work as "length" is unsolved reference. but i don't know how should i write, (or what keywords to google).
2. how can i get access to the name and spot of longest and shortest Runningpath to print them inside `printMaxMinPath()`? $min.name won't work

Any hints is very appreciated. Thank you for the kindness.

my codes with compile errors are as below:

```
 class  Runningpath(val name: String, val length: Int, val spot: String){                              
            override fun toString(): String= "The path $name ($length m) is near $spot"                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            fun printMaxMinPath (p: Array<Runningpath> , min:Int, max:Int) {                                  
                println("The shortest path is with $min m. It is the path $name near $spot")                  
                println("The longest path is with $max m. It is the path $name near $spot")                   
                                                                                                              
            }                                                                                                 
        }                 
        
        fun main() {                                                                                          
            println("Warming up")                                                                             
            val input1 = Runningpath("in Forest", 2000, "some houses")                                        
            val input2 = Runningpath("at lake", 1500, "a school")                                             
            val input3 = Runningpath("in mountain", 2800, "under sky")                                        
            val path = arrayOf(input1, input2, input3)                                                        
                                                                                
    line19   val max = path.length.max()                                                                       
        20   val min = path.length.min()                                                                       
            input1.printMaxMinPath(path, min, max)                                                            
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [maxBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-by.html) and [minBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/min-by.html) from the standard kotlin library to get object having maximum and minimum length, and then use their properties to print their values out.

```kotlin
data class Runningpath(val name: String, val length: Int, val spot: String)

fun main() {
    println("Warming up")
    val input1 = Runningpath("in Forest", 2000, "some houses")
    val input2 = Runningpath("at lake", 1500, "a school")
    val input3 = Runningpath("in mountain", 2800, "under sky")
    val paths = arrayOf(input1, input2, input3)

    printMaxMinPath(paths)
}

fun printMaxMinPath(paths: Array<RunningPath>) {
    val max = path.maxBy { it.length }
    val min = path.minBy { it.length }
    println("The shortest path is with ${min.length} m. It is the path ${min.name} near ${min.spot}")
    println("The longest path is with ${max.length} m. It is the path ${max.name} near ${max.spot}")
}
```

**Edit:** The minBy and maxBy may return null if the array provided was null. You have to safe assert them, you can do it before printing anything as follows.

```kotlin
fun printMaxMinPath(paths: Array<RunningPath>) {
    val max = path.maxBy { it.length }
    val min = path.minBy { it.length }
    min?.run { println("The shortest path is with $length m. It is the path $name near $spot") }
    max?.run { println("The longest path is with $length m. It is the path $name near $spot") }
}
```

Comment: Error message (Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Runningpath?) with the last two printlin, but can be fixed with ${min?.length}. may i ask, do you know why Runningpath is nullable type? it seems that i  never write any ?. with Runningpath. Thanks for your time and kindness, it helps me a lot.

Comment: @user12595983 it'll return `null` when there is no element in the array given.

Comment: Good, thanks! just a reminder abt typo, val path (at array), and $name (last 2 codes)